# Using jq to transform lines of key-values to json

Tags: json, jq

I am looking to transform a set of rows that are `key value` (space seperated) to JSON. I am hoping to use `jq-1.5` for this:

```
local.location.altitude   3.0
local.location.latitude   40.025495
local.location.longitude  -74.312501
local.orientation.pitch   0.0
local.orientation.roll    0.0
local.orientation.yaw     0.0
local.velocity.azimuth    0.0
local.velocity.elevation  0.0
local.velocity.magnitude  0.0
```

To

```
{
  "local.location.altitude": "3.0",
  "local.location.latitude": "40.025495",
  "local.location.longitude": "-74.312501",
  "local.orientation.pitch": "0.0",
  "local.orientation.roll": "0.0",
  "local.orientation.yaw": "0.0",
  "local.velocity.azimuth": "0.0",
  "local.velocity.elevation": "0.0",
  "local.velocity.magnitude": "0.0"
}
```

I am trying commands like:

```
./get-data | jq -R 'splits("\\s+")'
./get-data | jq -R 'splits("\\s+")|{ a : .[0], b : .[1] }
```

But unable to make it work. I feel I am close. Anyone know how to go from `{{key}} {{val}}` to `{"key": "value"}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some more approaches which all work well with jq 1.5:

- using `capture` and `from_entries`

```sh
jq -Rn '[inputs | capture("(?<key>\\S+)\\s+(?<value>.+)")] | from_entries'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/I4CAfutmbu)

- using `splits` and `reduce`

```sh
jq -Rn 'reduce (inputs | [splits("\\s+")]) as [$k,$v] ({}; .[$k] = $v)'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/cGIxzBdimS)

- using `splits` and `add`

```sh
jq -Rn '[inputs | [splits("\\s+")] as [$k, $v] | {($k): $v}] | add'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/HiZU4J10mA)

Comment: Really appreciate you showing the 3 different methods to make it happen! 

Any thoughts one which method is most memory and/or CPU efficient?

Comment: @E.S. The task basically boils down to two parts, namely slicing the input into pieces (using `capture` or `splits` or others), and composing the result object from those pieces (using `from_entries` or `reduce` or `add` or others). As you can mix and match them almost freely, there are actually plenty of more combinations. Regarding efficiency, using `inputs` (which already  features in all approaches) in combination with `reduce` works best with large amounts of data because of their (controllable) iterative nature.

Answer (score 1):

Use the raw input mode along with null input mode `-n`, so that you can get the whole input by `[inputs]` and further split by a regular expression indicating one or more whitespace characters.

The `split()` method can take a second argument to indicate any possible flags to provide.

Also inside the object formation, use `(..)` to generate key names.

```
jq -nR '[inputs] | map(split("\\s+"; "")) | map({(.[0]): .[1]}) | add'
```

If you want the values in numeric form, rather than as strings use `(.[1] | tonumber)` instead of just `.[1]`

[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Q_b9ZM9fil)